# Search and Extract a string with a specific keyword from a string

Tags: java, regex

I am processing a tsv file. I have a bunch of urls in one entry and I am looking for a specific url with '.ab.' keyword in it.

This is my data: http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexamplewith.AB.jpg

and I want output to be http://this/is/anexamplewith.ab.jpg

This is what I am using: '^http://.*[.AB.jpg]' but it's giving me entire string.
What RegEx can I use?

Thank you!

Comment: The simple way is to exclude the comma, but in general it is a wrong way since an url may contain a comma. So, a better way is to exclude all `h` characters that are the beginning of an url: `[^h]*(?:(?:\Bh|h(?!ttp:))[^h]*)*` instead of the dot. Read about `lookahead`s, character classes and regex special characters.

Comment: Try [`http:\/\/(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*\.ab\.(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*(?=$|http)`](https://regex101.com/r/nT5fA2/1).

Comment: @stribizhev 
Thank you so much! It worked. I am a new regex learner. It will be helpful if you can explain the logic. Also, I observed that it doesn't detect multiple occurrences. is there any additional regex I need to add?
Thanks!!

Comment: @ Casimir et Hippolyte
My data consists of different urls. url doesn't contain ',' but they are separated using commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `^http://.*[.AB.jpg]` matches `http://` at the beginning of the string and `.*` matches every character other than newline to the end (of line) looking for the last occurrence of the following characters - `.`, `A`, `B`, `.`, `j`, `p`, `g`. At the end you have `g` - thus the whole string is matched.

You can use

```
http:\/\/(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*\.ab\.(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*(?=$|http)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT5fA2/1)

Regex matches:

- `http:\/\/` - matches `http://`
- `(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*` - matches any symbol that is not starting the substring `http://` (thus ensuring the shortest window between the first `http://` and `.ab.`)
- `\.ab\.` - literal `.ab.`
- `(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*` - see above
- `(?=$|http)` - a lookahead that tells the engine to stop in front of end of string (`$`) or `http://`.

A Java implementation:

```
String str = "http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexamplewith.AB.jpg";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?i)http://(?:(?!http://).)*\\.ab\\.(?:(?!http://).)*(?=$|http)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output of the [sample demo program](http://ideone.com/5sFmSm):

```
http://this/is/anexamplewith.AB.jpg
```

**REPLACEMENT**

To replace that match, you just need to use a `replaceAll`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)http://(?:(?!http://).)*\\.ab\\.(?:(?!http://).)*(?=$|http)", "");
```

Comment: my regex is failing when I am testing in my java code.Can you please suggest me whats going wrong?
Java Code:

public class RegexTry {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(http://(?:(?!http://).)*.AB.(?:(?!http://).)*(?=$|http))");
  String mydata = "http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexample.jpg,http://this/is/anexamplewith.AB.jpg";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if(matcher.matches()) {
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
}
}

Comment: I added a Java implementation.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks again @stribizhev

Comment: Further more, I want to return the original string excluding the group(0) url which contains .ab.
This is what I am doing:
while (matcher.find()) {
  str.replace(matcher.group(0), "");
     System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
     System.out.println(str);
 }
But the replace operation is not performing correctly. Can you please guide me?

Comment: You just forget to assign the replaced string back to the variable. And you do not need any matcher.find.

Comment: If I don't use the matcher.find, how is going to loop through and find the required substring?
Didn't get this part!
Thank you @stribizhev

Comment: You just forget to assign the replaced string back to the variable.